# Flutter add value from custom TextFormField and automatically show the value in another customtextformfield

Tags: flutter, textfield, onchange, textformfield

I have a custom Textfield, In my application, the user enters an amount in the textfield with the label quantity, the amount entered should be multiplied with value in another textfield(the value in this textfield is from list on the previous page called price). The total should be automatically calculated in another textfield called total. Below is code that I have tried.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kingstar/res/custom_colors.dart';

class CustomFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomFormField({
    Key? key,
    required TextEditingController controller,
    // required FocusNode focusNode,
    required TextInputType keyboardType,
    required TextInputAction inputAction,
    required String label,
    required String hint,
    required Function(String value) validator,
    required Function(String value) onChanged,
    this.isObscure = false,
    this.isCapitalized = false,
    this.maxLines = 1,
    this.isLabelEnabled = true,
    this.readOnly = false,
  })  : _emailController = controller,
        // _emailFocusNode = focusNode,
        _keyboardtype = keyboardType,
        _inputAction = inputAction,
        _label = label,
        _hint = hint,
        _validator = validator,
        super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController _emailController;
  // final FocusNode _emailFocusNode;
  final TextInputType _keyboardtype;
  final TextInputAction _inputAction;
  final String _label;
  final String _hint;
  final bool isObscure;
  final bool isCapitalized;
  final int maxLines;
  final bool isLabelEnabled;
  final Function(String) _validator;
  final bool readOnly;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      maxLines: maxLines,
      controller: _emailController,
      readOnly: readOnly,
      // focusNode: _emailFocusNode,
      keyboardType: _keyboardtype,
      obscureText: isObscure,
      textCapitalization:
      isCapitalized ? TextCapitalization.words : TextCapitalization.none,
      textInputAction: _inputAction,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      cursorColor: CustomColors.firebaseYellow,
      validator: (value) => _validator(value!),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: isLabelEnabled ? _label : null,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: CustomColors.firebaseYellow),
        hintText: _hint,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        errorStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: CustomColors.firebaseAmber,
            width: 2,
          ),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: CustomColors.firebaseGrey.withOpacity(0.5),
          ),
        ),
        errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            width: 2,
          ),
        ),
        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            width: 2,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class EditItemForm extends StatefulWidget {



  final String currentName;
  final String currentPrice;
  final String currentQuantity;
  final String documentId;

  const EditItemForm({
    required this.currentName,
    required this.currentPrice,
    required this.currentQuantity,
    required this.documentId,
  });

  @override
  _EditItemFormState createState() => _EditItemFormState();
}

class _EditItemFormState extends State<EditItemForm> {
  final _editItemFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final DocumentReference docId = _salesCollection.doc();

  bool _isProcessing = false;


  late TextEditingController _nameController;
  late TextEditingController _priceController;
  late TextEditingController _quantityAvailableController;
  late TextEditingController _quantityController;
  late TextEditingController _totalController;
  int? _total = 0;


  late SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  late String documentId = "", buyer_name = "", buyer_phonenumber="", buyer_email="", buyer_address="", seller_name="", seller_location = "";
 late int total;

  void _onChange() {
    setState(() {
      _total = (int.parse( widget.currentPrice) * int.parse(_quantityController.text));
      print(int.parse( widget.currentPrice) * int.parse(_quantityController.text));
    });
  }

  textListener() {
    _total = (int.parse(_priceController.text) * int.parse(_quantityController.text));
    print("Current Text is ${_total.toString()}");
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    _nameController = TextEditingController(
      text: widget.currentName,
    );
    _priceController = TextEditingController(
      text: widget.currentPrice,
    );
    _quantityAvailableController = TextEditingController(
      text: widget.currentQuantity,
    );
    _quantityController = TextEditingController(
        text: widget.currentQuantity,
    );

    _totalController = TextEditingController(
      text: widget.currentQuantity,
    );

    super.initState();

    _onChange();

    _quantityController.addListener(textListener);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(
        key: _editItemFormKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 8.0,
                right: 8.0,
                bottom: 24.0,
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 24.0),
                  Text(
                    'Feed Name',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: CustomColors.firebaseGrey,
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                      letterSpacing: 1,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  CustomFormField(
                    readOnly: true,
                    isLabelEnabled: false,
                    controller: _nameController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    inputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    validator: (value) => Validator.validateField(
                      value: value,
                    ),
                    label: 'Feed',
                    hint: 'Feed Name', onChanged: (String value) {  },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24.0),
                  Text(
                    'Price',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: CustomColors.firebaseGrey,
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                      letterSpacing: 1,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  CustomFormField(
                    // readOnly: true,
                    isLabelEnabled: false,
                    controller: _priceController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    inputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    validator: (value) => Validator.validateField(
                      value: value,
                    ),
                    label: 'Price',
                    hint: 'Price for' + widget.currentName,
                    onChanged: (value) => _onChange,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24,),
                  Text(
                    'Quanity Available',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: CustomColors.firebaseGrey,
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                      letterSpacing: 1,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  CustomFormField(
                    readOnly: true,
                    isLabelEnabled: false,
                    controller: _quantityAvailableController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    validator: (value) => Validator.validateField(
                      value: value,
                    ),
                    label: 'Quantity',
                    hint: 'Quantity available for' + widget.currentName,
                    onChanged: (value) => _onChange,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24,),
                  Text(
                    'Quanity ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: CustomColors.firebaseGrey,
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                      letterSpacing: 1,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  CustomFormField(
                    isLabelEnabled: false,
                    controller: _quantityController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    validator: (value) => Validator.validateField(
                      value: value,
                    ),
                    label: 'Quantity',
                    hint: 'Enter your quantity',
                    onChanged: (value) => _onChange,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24,),
                  Text(
                    'Total ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: CustomColors.firebaseGrey,
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                      letterSpacing: 1,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  CustomFormField(
                    readOnly: true,
                    isLabelEnabled: false,
                    controller: _totalController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    validator: (value) => Validator.validateField(
                      value: value,
                    ),
                    label: 'Total',
                    hint: 'Total',
                    onChanged: (String value) {  },
                  ),
                  Text(
                      _total!.toString()
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            _isProcessing
                ? Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                  CustomColors.firebaseOrange,
                ),
              ),
            ) ,
              
  }
}
```

I have tried using the onChange both inside the customFormField but I am still not having the having the value changed in the last CustomFormField with the label total or in the text widget below it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextEditingController`

here is working demo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          // value "passed" from other screen
          child: MyWidget(price: 12),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  double price;
  MyWidget({required this.price}) {
    controllerPrice.text = this.price.toString();
  }
  // price "from other screen"
  TextEditingController controllerPrice = TextEditingController();
  // controller to update Total value
  TextEditingController controllerTotal = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Text("Quantity:"),
      TextField(onChanged: (String t) {
        controllerTotal.text =
            (double.parse(t) * double.parse(controllerPrice.text)).toString();
      }),
      Text("Price:"),
      TextField(readOnly: true, controller: controllerPrice),
      Text("Total:"),
      TextField(readOnly: true, controller: controllerTotal),
    ]);
  }
}
```

}

And dartpad:
https://dartpad.dev/?id=051b6df715ecfa9b54e5a771c3927057&null_safety=true

Of course you need to handle input when you delete everything from Quantity field.